# I got an error when trying to pass a pointer to a procedure in free pascal

Tags: arrays, function, pointers, freepascal

everyone!   *[I'm using **free pascal** in **Lazarus** framework]*
I'm trying to pass the pointer to integer into a function (or a procedure, it doesn't matter), but free pascal doesn't like it... I've done a lot of programming in other languages, but now I need to remember exactly free pascal, and I can't google it, there is a lot of strange information, but nothing useful *(as usual, as always)*.

Here it is:

```pascal
procedure foo(a: ^integer);
begin
  a^+= 1;
end;

var
  a: integer;
begin
  a:= 0;
  foo(@a);
  writeln(a);
  readln(a);
end.
```

and a strange mistake which complains about the first line:

```bash
project1.lpr(1,19) Error: Type identifier expected
project1.lpr(1,19) Fatal: Syntax error, ")" expected but "const char" found
```

of course, I can just write var in the brackets of the function like `procedure foo(var c)` and play with it like with a usual variable, but I don't want. I want to make exactly the way I would do it in the C++, for example:

```cpp
void foo(int* a) {
    (a*)++;
}
int main() {
    int a = 0;
    foo(&a);
    cout << a; //Thanks -> like -> subscribe -> etc.
}
```

***Also I wan't to know, how to pass the array of *something* into a function/procedure without using var in brackets.***

Help me please i would appreciate it!

I've tried to pass the pointer to function => strange error mistake
I've tried to pass an array to funuction, with various ways, it doesn't work(

Comment: You wrote `^pointer`, which would be `void **` in C++.  Did you mean `^integer` or did you mean `pointer`?  And as a word of advice, when you learn a new language, it is unhealthy to try to write code exactly like your old language.  Learn how to do it correctly.   https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse15.html

Comment: And Pascal does not have the `+=` operator.  I suspect it's complaining about `a^+=1;`.  You can write `a^ := a^ + 1;` or `inc(a^);`.

Comment: I've already watched this documentation and tried to write like there, also I've tried to wrote like in examples in YouTube videos, but it doesn't work(

Comment: does, it has. Maybe you don't remember new versions of free pascal

Comment: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu44.html#x151-17500012.8.1

Comment: If I read the documentation correctly, you cannot have a parameter with a `^` modifier.  That's only for variable declarations.  You need to use `var`.  That has exactly the same semantics.

Answer (score 1):

C can not pass by reference, pascal can.

So, one solution (preferred) is:

```
procedure foo(var a: integer);
begin
  a += 1   // or inc(a)
end;

var
  a: integer;

begin
  a:= 0;
  foo(a);
  ...
```

Also notice that you don't need to take the address with "@".

Another solution, *not* preferred, is:

```
procedure foo(a: Pinteger);
begin
  a^ += 1
end;

var
  a: integer;

begin
  a:= 0;
  foo(@a);
  ...
```

This is more C-like and, this time, you need to take the address with "@" to generate a pointer. "Pinteger", in freepascal, is already declared, but you could declare it yourself with:

```
type
  pinteger = ^integer;
```

As already noted in comments, it is common to use constructs from a known language when starting with another language. But perhaps... the first thing one should do is to compare the old and new language to understand the differences and take the best from the new language (pascal in this case). About this particular question, differences are:

1. Pascal can pass arguments by reference
2. Pascal can not create types "on the fly", for example inside a function declaration.